# Dozer to check memory leak

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, nginx

I have a python app running on django , gunicorn and nginx , everything works perfectly but am experiencing some issues with memory .  While running this app most of the memory consumed by its process and after some time app becomes slow .

Now I would like to check my app whether there is any memory leaks.  I have searched on google a lot , at last I got python script named "Dozer" to find the memory leaks on python apps .

But the problem I was not able to configure this app on my environment . On docs they mentioned about the configuration with apache .

Does anyone know how to configure this plugin with nginx ?

Any help would be appreciated .

Also please let me know if there are any other plugins available to check the memory leaks on python apps .

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dozer .2 Alpha.

You may also try

1) [linesman](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/linesman) or

2) keas.profile or

3) [repoze.profile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.profile/1.3)